# WP8 LongListSelector: Add new item without scrolling to top

Tags: windows-phone-8

When I add items to the ItemsSource of a LongListSelector, the LongListSelector automatically scrolls to the top. Is there anyway to disable this?

I tried to use the ScrollTo function after loading, but that is not good enough since I want to stay at the exact same scroll position (meaning I don't want the LostListSelector to scroll at all, when I add a new item to its ItemsSource).

Comment: Can you post the code which is causing it to scroll to the top? That shouldn't happen.

Comment: That's default behaviour for the wp8 LLS, when you add new items to an already loaded list, it will scroll. I always keep track of the last item and do the ScrollTo - only option I know ( cfr http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php/243649-WP8-LongListSelector-ScrollTo?p=929801#post929801 )

Comment: But doesn't that appear 'laggy'? Remember I don't want to scroll anywhere when I add an element, so if I do ScrollTo an element that currently appear in my View, won't it move it a bit, so that the element I scroll to, is in the middle of the screen or something like it?

I want behavior like the 6tag app, if you've tried it. I have a list of images, when I click the last image (a 'load more pictures' image) I want to load a set of new images, add them to the list, and stay at the scrolling position, that I was when I clicked the 'load more pictures' image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used a List instead of ObservableCollection as the ItemsSource for the LongListSelector and that I used the Lists set function, which implements NotifyPropertyChanged, to assign images to the LongListSelector. This NotifyPropertyChanged event causes the LongListSelector to scroll to index 0 of the ItemsSource.

So I solved it by changing the ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection and use Add instead of the setter for the ObservableCollection.